# How to resize image on upload in rails app using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In my Rails app, I have the below:

```
  has_attached_file :image

  def picture_from_url(url)
    self.image = URI.parse(url)
  end
```

I would like to resize the image when it gets saved as well but am not sure how to do this.  I would like the width to be 300px and the height to scale proportionally to this.  Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the readme on github: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Quick Start

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

If you upload an image, you can set different styles..in your case 300px.

Comment: If you upload an image through a form, you won´t need an url.. or what do you mean exactly?